# How to enable usage of SSH keys pair without exposing it

Tags: ssh, security, authentication, openssh, key-authentication

We have a `topsecret@remote.org` SSH account that can be accessed with SSH key pair `ts_key.pub/ts_key.priv` from our gateway server (`gateway.org`). We have many sysadmins that need to access that account. Each of them has its own SSH account on `gateway.org`, like `sysadmin1@gateway.org`.

Is there a way to keep `ts_key.pub/ts_key.priv` on `gateway.org` and enable sysadmins to use it, but **without exposing it** to the sysadmins? So if one of them leaves his job, and his account on `gateway.org` is closed, then he will not be able to use `ts_key.pub/ts_key.priv` anymore.

Update: I was suggested (by nice people on IRC/#OpenSSH) to encrypt the private key with a passphrase and then to use ssh-agent/ssh-add. However I didn't figured out the details...

Comment: "if one of them leaves his job" you should assign new credentials

Comment: @Fabian, there is no reason to change `ts_key.pub/ts_key.priv` if the sysadmin that left the job never saw this key pair (even though he used it all the time). Otherwise it is not manageable. That is the point of the question.

Comment: Would that be an option for you - to put personal admins public keys on remote.org and allow gateway to forward ssh agent?
That will not require shared keypair at all.

Comment: @Tagwint, for certain reasons, sysadmin account/keys management should be done on gateway server. Thank you!

Comment: @Debian_yadav Please don't use code formatting for random words. Code formatting is for code.

Comment: If you don't do any cleanup after an outgoing, disgruntled, sysadmin, what stops them from accessing your system with some other key that they may have given access to on the system?

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you could prefix the key in the authorized_keys file of topsecret@remote.org with a "from=ip.address.of.gateway.org", effectively making the key work only if the connection comes from the gateway system.

See "man sshd" for more details.

Another possibility would be to have the private key on a separate account on `gateway.org` that has logins disabled. Let's call that account `secretkeeper` for example. Then you could give the sysadmins limited sudo access to that account like this (`sudoers` file syntax):

```
User_Alias ADMINUSERS=sysadmin1, sysadmin2, sysadmin3 #...etc.

ADMINUSERS ALL=(secretkeeper) /usr/bin/ssh secretremote
```

Have `~secretkeeper/.ssh/config` specify as much of the connection parameters as possible, for user-friendliness:

```
Host secretremote
    User topsecret
    HostName remote.org
    EscapeChar none
    IdentityFile /some/where/ts_key.priv
```

Now your `sysadmin1` and others will be able to run `sudo -u secretkeeper ssh secretremote`, but no other commands via `sudo` (unless there are other `sudoers` definitions). `secretremote` is just a keyword that can be anything, as long as it is the same in both the `sudoers` and `~secretkeeper/.ssh/config` files.

Since the command specified in the `sudoers` file includes parameters, only that specific command will be accepted. Then `sudo` will run the command (and only that command) as the `secretkeeper` user, which can read the SSH configuration file and the private key, and then establish the connection. And since the `sudo` session is only running that one `ssh` command, once SSH is disconnected, the `sudo` session will end; there will be no interactive shell running as the `secretkeeper` user.

Of course, all this requires that your sysadmin users must not have root access to the `gateway.org` system.

Comment: It's a good point, and I'll most probably do it as additional measure, but I prefer to make this "topsecret" master key usable but not accessible for sysadmins... Thank you!

Comment: @user1876484 If your "sysadmins" have root access to the box, there's nothing you can do if that key also lives on the box. You will need to redesign the solution for whatever it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I added another solution, now that I'm no longer phone-posting.

Comment: @Patrick, no sysadmins do not have root access to the box, I also was told to encrypt the key and to use ssh-agent/ssh-add - but I didn't figure yet how...

Comment: @telcoM, after several days of thinking I came to the conclusion that your approach suits my case better than `ssh-agent/ssh-add` as my sysadmins really do not require root access. Actually it would be perfect if you could even further tighten the security in your answer and disable for the sysadmins **all** other commands, even those that do not require `sudo` as this server is supposed to be a gateway only.